# Proguard warnings with obfuscated class names when generating release apk

Tags: android, proguard

When I run following command:

```
gradlew assebleRelease
```

but got some weird warnings:

```
Warning: a.a.e.a.i: can't find referenced class a.a.e.a.i$a.a.e.a.o
Warning: a.a.e.s: can't find referenced class a.a.e.s$a.a.e.t
Warning: a.a.e.s: can't find referenced class a.a.e.s$a.a.e.t
Warning: a.a.e.t: can't find referenced class a.a.e.s$a.a.e.t
Warning: a.a.e.t: can't find referenced class a.a.e.s$a.a.e.t
```

I've tried lots of -keep -dontwarn lines, but no one solved this issue. Why a obfuscated class name appears on the right side of these warnings?

Answer (score 0):

you should try -

> `-keep public class models.* {   *; }`

or you will have to configure according to your library used in your project

also try this with the above -

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.**
-dontwarn okio.Okio
-dontwarn okio.DeflaterSink
-keep class javax.**
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
```

it worked for me. i hope it will work for you as well

Comment: How are these rules even remotely related to the question?

Comment: dont know but they worked for me. he can try atleast

Comment: And you had the *same* problem as the OP?